# Web browser closes after upi payment through Razorpay

Tags: ios, safari, payment-gateway, razorpay, upi

we are using web app to order and pay for items. we are using razorpay payment gateway. for some iphone user we noticed after they select upi payment then they are redirected to respective upi app and after there payment web browser automatically closing from background. unable to debug why this happen.

i want to stop this auto closing of browser after payment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.